# Using icon type from oracle database to call an icon and use it as marker icon in leaflet

Tags: oracle, icons, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have my icon type as a column which is item[1] in my oracle database but I can't seem to get it to show on my leaflet map. It the second column in my query but doesn't seem to work when I add it to my marker

```
  var map = L.map("mapid", {
  zoom: 10,
  center: [55.7363, -6.1771],
  layers: [NLS, googleearth, OpenTopoMap],
  zoomControl: false,
  attributionControl: true
 });    

var baseLayers = {
"Historical Map": NLS,
"Topographical map": OpenTopoMap,
"Aerial Imagery": googleearth.addTo(map)
};
L.control.layers(baseLayers,null,{collapsed:false}).addTo(map);

var markers= L.markerClusterGroup({
});

var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconSize:     [38, 95],
        shadowSize:   [50, 64],
        iconAnchor:   [22, 94],
        shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
        popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
    }
});


var icons2 = {
    worship: new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '../icon/church.png'}),
    grave: new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '../icon/grave.png'}),
    jura: new LeafIcon({iconUrl: '../icon/farm.png'})
}
{% for item in markers %}
var marker{{ item[0] }} = L.marker({{ item[2:] }},{icon: icons2({{ item[1] 
  }}) });
 markers.addLayer(marker{{ item[0] }});
 map.addLayer(markers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to Leaflet docs: the Marker `icon` option does not expect your icon image path, but an `L.icon`.

That icon takes your image path within its own options, alongside other information to properly position that image on the marker coordinates.